# How to start Dockerized Python Flask app with https instead of http?

Tags: python, docker, ssl, flask, https

I have a REST api server developed with **Python & Flask framework** and deployed in the main server with **Docker**. When I build & start the docker container by `sudo docker-compose build` & `sudo docker-compose up`, the docker container starts at `http://0.0.0.0:5000/` or `localhost` and using port `5000`.

This works fine in `non-ssl` environment or browser or domain. But recently my main website (suppose `www.example.com`) started using **ssl certificates**. To communicate with main site I have to serve my **apis** in `https` instead of `http`.

Now I am trying to use this code to start server in https mode, but getting some errors.

My code :

```
import ssl
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
ctx.load_cert_chain('certificate.pem', 'privateKey.pem')

.
.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0',ssl_context=ctx)
```

Here is my error:

[image]

**What will be the proper procedure to start Docker supported Python Flask app in https mode?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 2 days of tiresome work I found the proper solution. My domain got 2 files when implemented **ssl** or **https**. One is **mydomain_com.crt** file, another is **private.key**

I found these 2 files in my server's main directory. As I am using Apache, then I found these files in **/etc/var/www/html** folder.

I copied 2 files as follows:

1. copied the license from **mydomain_com.crt** file and paste in a **text file** then renamed it **certificate.pem**
2. copied the license from **private.key** and paste in a **text file** then renamed it **privateKey.pem**

Then I used my domain's default ssl certificate into my Flask app like this:

```
import ssl
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
ctx.load_cert_chain('certificate.pem', 'privateKey.pem')
.
.
.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', ssl_context=ctx)
```

And exposed the **2 ports** in my **Dockerfile** like this :

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

After restart, my Dockerized Flask app now working with my domain's default ssl certificate and serving the APIs correctly.

Example : https://example.com:5000/getUsers