# Docker VPS work with HTTP but not with HTTPS

Tags: docker, apache, http, vps, certbot

I am trying to host my Flask Rest API from Docker container within a VPS (apache). Its working fine with `http` but not working with `https`.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11
# Virtual envs not needed inside container
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY . /app
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["flask", "--app=app", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

running `$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:5000 myapp:latest` allow me to run `http://myapphostwebsite.com:8080/user/12345` on Postman. I could then retrieve data but when using `https://myapphostwebsite.com:8080/user/12345`, I got this Postman error :

```
Error: write EPROTO 5543930632:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:
```

And the Docker Log gives this

```
code 400, message Bad request version ('À\x13À') \x16\x03\x01\x00ü\x01\x00\x00ø\x...
```

I don't know what to do. How to access my Docker container outside with https?

PS : I used `Certbot` to setup SSL on my VPS

Comment: Are you terminating the https connection in apache vps or forwarding it to the container?

Comment: terminating  in apache vps

Comment: Figured out the problem. Just had to setup ssl for my Python Flask app as follow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901178/how-to-start-dockerized-python-flask-app-with-https-instead-of-http

Answer (score 1):

This is because Alpine mirrors do not have CA certificates installed by default. You can fix this issue by following the steps below:

```bash
apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
```

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work